# How to scan ENTIRE GITHUB Repository for certain files?

Tags: github

I want to quickly scan an entire repository to find certain files.
To be more precise, I need to look for files that have a .yaml (or.yml) extension.

Comment: How it that related to `github-actions` ? you wan to do it in bash in github action ?

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski I am new to github and its operations. So still learning things. I though github actions could have a way!

Comment: It does if you need to do it automatically and run as an Action - then you just use bash

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski Could you elaborate on this particular bash?

Comment: Why not using the `git ls-files '*.yaml'` (or `git ls-files '*.yml'`) command at the repository root? Git is already installed on github actions, you would just need to use the `actions/checkout` before to access the repository workspace. Then, you could export it on a file or a env variable.

Comment: I made an example here: [workflow run](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/actions/runs/1813514815) and [workflow file](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/45-get-all-yaml-files.yml). Let me know if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Why is this question tagged **mysql**?